# Vaadin 14 Combo box scroll to selected value

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

is is possible that when i click combo box drop down it will scroll to the selected value

Vaadin 14 combox box scrollToSelected value is not found..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Vaadin >= 10.

You can vote and comment on this issue: https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/1118